# Get content of docx file which saved in mysql dabase as blob type in php

Tags: php, mysql, blob, docx

I am saving docx file as BLOB type in mysql dadabase. after the saveing i am trying to see the content of the file through fetching the content of filed but it is showing some unreadable content.This this is working well for file having extention .doc but i don't know why it is not working for the .docx file.If any answer please help with proper explanation.

Comment: Can we see some code? How do you output the file? I'd like to see what headers your using

Answer (score 1):

Make a query to select the data, then put the result in a variable.
Use file_put_content to get the docx file. Just be carefull with header.

To read it, the process is different from a doc. You have to "unzip" the docx and read the xml file inside it.  You can use this function:

```
<?php

/*Name of the document file*/
$document = 'filename.docx';

/**Function to extract text*/
function extracttext($filename) {
    //Check for extension
    $ext = end(explode('.', $filename));

    //if its docx file
    if($ext == 'docx')
    $dataFile = "word/document.xml";
    //else it must be odt file
    else
    $dataFile = "content.xml";     

    //Create a new ZIP archive object
    $zip = new ZipArchive;

    // Open the archive file
    if (true === $zip->open($filename)) {
        // If successful, search for the data file in the archive
        if (($index = $zip->locateName($dataFile)) !== false) {
            // Index found! Now read it to a string
            $text = $zip->getFromIndex($index);
            // Load XML from a string
            // Ignore errors and warnings
            $xml = DOMDocument::loadXML($text, LIBXML_NOENT | LIBXML_XINCLUDE | LIBXML_NOERROR | LIBXML_NOWARNING);
            // Remove XML formatting tags and return the text
            return strip_tags($xml->saveXML());
        }
        //Close the archive file
        $zip->close();
    }

    // In case of failure return a message
    return "File not found";
}

echo extracttext($document);
?>
```

(source of the code: http://www.botskool.com/geeks/how-extract-text-docx-or-odt-files-using-php)

Answer (score 0):

Docx is a zipped file type [See Tag Wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/docx/info)

That's why you can't get the content of the document from the raw content.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution :

```
"update blob_table set blob_col='LOAD_FILE('$tmp_name')";
```

where `$tmp_name` is the file you upload, and this is the answer for this 6 years old question, using `LOAD_FILE`  function. may be this is a newly added function to **mysql**.