# found unreadable content when open Word file downloado from MySQL database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, download, ms-word

I have Word files stored in a MySQL database, I download them with this code:

```
header("Content-Type: application/doc");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"filename.docx\"");
echo $row['blob_file'];
```

but when I open them I get this warning:
***found unreadable content in filename.docx.  Do you want to recover the contents of this document?  If you trust the source of this document, click Yes.***
if I click yes it opens normally but how can I avoid this warning?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18913736/get-content-of-docx-file-which-saved-in-mysql-dabase-as-blob-type-in-php

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes I thought about it so I tried uploading it directly using MySQL LOAD_FILE() function but it didn't work.

Comment: @Patrick I tried putting the file in C:/inetpub/wwwroot/site/filename.docx and using `echo extracttext("C:/inetpub/wwwroot/site/filename.docx");`with same headers but it didn't work

Comment: Have you tried changing content-type? Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document

And
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

Comment: I tried `Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary` both with `Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document` and with `Content-Type: application/doc` but with no luck