# PHP error `Only variables should be passed by reference`

Tags: php, mysql

**Goal**

I have never touched `PHP`.

My goal is to retrieve `BLOB` .docx content from MySQL. I have found this resource to help me: [Get content of docx file which saved in mysql dabase as blob type in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18913736/get-content-of-docx-file-which-saved-in-mysql-dabase-as-blob-type-in-php)

I have just installed something called *xampp* along with *Apache* and *PHP*.

Created a folder within *htdocs* called *Techincal*. Inside there I have 2 files called *test3.php* and *test.docx*

At this moment I am not using *MySQL* at all. I am trying to see what *PHP* can do for me.

I have copied the code from the link above.

**Code**

```
<?php

/*Name of the document file*/
$document = 'test.docx';

/**Function to extract text*/
function extracttext($filename) {
    //Check for extension
    $ext = end(explode('.', $filename));

    //if its docx file
    if($ext == 'docx')
    $dataFile = "word/document.xml";
    //else it must be odt file
    else
    $dataFile = "content.xml";

    //Create a new ZIP archive object
    $zip = new ZipArchive;

    // Open the archive file
    if (true === $zip->open($filename)) {
        // If successful, search for the data file in the archive
        if (($index = $zip->locateName($dataFile)) !== false) {
            // Index found! Now read it to a string
            $text = $zip->getFromIndex($index);
            // Load XML from a string
            // Ignore errors and warnings
            $xml = DOMDocument::loadXML($text, LIBXML_NOENT | LIBXML_XINCLUDE | LIBXML_NOERROR | LIBXML_NOWARNING);
            // Remove XML formatting tags and return the text
            return strip_tags($xml->saveXML());
        }
        //Close the archive file
        $zip->close();
    }

    // In case of failure return a message
    return "File not found";
}

echo extracttext($document);
?>
```

When I run it on *localhost* - been following instructions on other websites on how to `run PHP files`.

**Output**

```
Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference in C:\xampp\htdocs\technical\test3.php on line 9
Testing
```

Comment: A more reliable way to get a filename extension is to use [`pathinfo`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) i.e. `$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);`

Answer (score 2):

You need to store the result of explode() statement on line no 9 into a variable and then that variable should be passed to end function. This will resolve your problem.
Refer the below-corrected code.

```
       <?php

    /*Name of the document file*/
    $document = 'test.docx';

    /**Function to extract text*/
    function extracttext($filename) {
        //Check for extension
$tmp = explode('.', $filename);
        $ext = end( $tmp );

        //if its docx file
        if($ext == 'docx')
        $dataFile = "word/document.xml";
        //else it must be odt file
        else
        $dataFile = "content.xml";

        //Create a new ZIP archive object
        $zip = new ZipArchive;

        // Open the archive file
        if (true === $zip->open($filename)) {
            // If successful, search for the data file in the archive
            if (($index = $zip->locateName($dataFile)) !== false) {
                // Index found! Now read it to a string
                $text = $zip->getFromIndex($index);
                // Load XML from a string
                // Ignore errors and warnings
                $xml = DOMDocument::loadXML($text, LIBXML_NOENT | LIBXML_XINCLUDE | LIBXML_NOERROR | LIBXML_NOWARNING);
                // Remove XML formatting tags and return the text
                return strip_tags($xml->saveXML());
            }
            //Close the archive file
            $zip->close();
        }

        // In case of failure return a message
        return "File not found";
    }

    echo extracttext($document);
    ?>
```

Comment: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$ext' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\technical\php.php on line 10`

Comment: There's a semicolon missing after `$tmp = explode('.', $filename)`

Comment: Added the missing semicolon.

Comment: Images are stored in word/media/ you need to write code to show them. Use something like - https://github.com/xylude/Docx-to-HTML

Answer (score 0):

Function `end()` need an array by reference (read: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.end.php) and you just put there a result of other function. You have to store result of `explode()` to some variable and that variable put to `end()`.